# Using jQuery to auto calculate amount

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a simple form to auto calculate amount entered in the Amount field.

The Total Sum field is only updated upon entering the first row's Amount field. Total Sum field is not updated for subsequent rows.`

```html
<?php
    $sno = 1;
?>

  <html>

  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      
      #summation {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #174C68;
      }
      
      .amt {
        background-color: #FEFFB0;
        //font-weight: bold;
        text-align: right;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th />&nbsp;
                <th>Invoice No.</th>
                <th>Invoice Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr id='addr0'>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $sno;?>
                </td>
                <td width="40px"><input class="txt" type="text" name="invoiceNo" style="text-transform:uppercase" /></td>
                <td><input type="date" name="date" /></td>
                <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" /></td>
                <td><input class="amt" type="number" name="amt" min="0" step="0.01" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr id='addr1'></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left">Add Row</button>

      <table>
        <tr id="summation">
          <td align="right" colspan="3">Total Sum :</td>
          <td align="right" colspan="2"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 1;
        var j = 1;
        $("#add_row").click(function() {
          $('#addr' + i).html("<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td><input type='text' name='invoiceNo" + i + "' class='form-control input-md' style='text-transform:uppercase'/></td><td><input type='date' name='date" + i + "' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='text" + i + "' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='number' name='amt" + i + "' class='amt' min='0' step='0.01'/></td>");

          $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
          i++;
        });

        $('.amt').each(function() {

          $(this).keyup(function() {
            calculateSum();
          });
        });

        $('.amt' + j).each(function() {

          $(this).keyup(function() {
            calculateSum();
          });
          j++;
        });
      });

      function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        $(".amt").each(function() {

          if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
          }

        });
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
      }
    </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

The Total Sum field for subsequent rows is updated only when I change the contents in 1st row's Amount field.

How can I update the Total Sum automatically whenever the Amount field is entered for subsequent rows?

Thank you.

*** Updates ***
I've updated my code as per Paul's suggestion.

```html
<?php
    $sno = 1;
    $i = 0;
?>

  <html>

  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      
      #summation {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #174C68;
      }
      
      .amt {
        //background-color: #FEFFB0;
        //font-weight: bold;
        text-align: right;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="form" id="form" action="data.php">

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic" border="1" style="border:2px solid black;border-collapse:collapse">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th />&nbsp;
                  <th>Invoice No.</th>
                  <th>Invoice Date</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
                  <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr id='addr0'>
                  <td>
                    <?php echo $sno;?>
                  </td>
                  <td width="40px"><input class="txt" type="text" name="invoiceNo[<?php echo $i; ?>][invoiceNo]" style="text-transform:uppercase" /></td>
                  <td><input type="date" name="date[<?php echo $i; ?>][date]" /></td>
                  <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="desc[<?php echo $i; ?>][desc]" /></td>
                  <td><input class="amt" type="number" name="amt[<?php echo $i; ?>][amt]" step="0.01" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id='addr1'></tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left" type="button">Add Row</button>

        <table>
          <tr id="summation">
            <td align="right" colspan="3">Total Sum :</td>
            <td align="right" colspan="2"><span id="sum">0.00</span></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <br>

      <tr>
        <!--<td align="center"><button type="button" id="btn-ser1">Submit</button></td>-->
        <td align="center"><button type="submit" id="btn-ser1">Submit</button></td>
      </tr>

      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var i = 1;
          $('#add_row').click(function() {
            $('#addr' + i).html("<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td><input type='text' name='invoiceNo[" + i + "][invoiceNo]' class='form-control input-md' style='text-transform:uppercase'/></td><td><input type='date' name='date[" + i + "][date]' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='desc[" + i + "][desc]' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='number' name='amt[" + i + "][amt]' class='amt' min='0' step='0.01'/></td>");

            $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
            i++;
          });
        });

        $('#tab_logic').on('change', '.amt', function() {
          this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
        });

        // Use an event delegate on amt
        $('#tab_logic').on('change', '.amt', function() {
          calculateSum();
        });

        function calculateSum() {

          var sum = 0;
          $('.amt').each(function() {

            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
              sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

          });
          $('#sum').html(sum.toFixed(2));
          $('#total').val(sum);
        }

        //$('#btn-ser1').click(function(){
        //      data_array = $('#form').serialize();
        //      alert(data_array);

        $('form').submit(function() {
          data_array = $('#form').serialize();
          //alert(data_array);
          $('#arr').val(data_array);
        });
      </script>
      <!--<input type="hidden" name="sno" value="<?php echo $sno; ?>">-->
      <input type="hidden" id="total" name="total" />
      <input type="hidden" id="arr" name="arr" />
    </body>

  </html>
```

When I submit the form & print the array, I get this sample output:

invoiceNo[0][invoiceNo]=a1&date[0][date]=2021-02-18&desc[0][desc]=a1&amt[0][amt]=1.47&invoiceNo[1][invoiceNo]=b2&date[1][date]=2021-02-17&desc[1][desc]=b2&amt[1][amt]=2.58&invoiceNo[2][invoiceNo]=c3&date[2][date]=2021-02-16&desc[2][desc]=c3&amt[2][amt]=3.69&total=7.74&arr=

How can I get the recurring values of invoiceNo, date, desc & amt to insert into a SQL statement?

Comment: I don't _believe_ that you need `i` either (but I could be wrong). How does the output look without using the `i` reference? I was expecting to see `invoiceNo[]`, then the same for `date[]` and the others. I'll copy what you have to check myself too.

Comment: Ok, it is as I thought, `i` is not needed to make indexes. Use those four inputs with the `[]` with the name. Then, you can process those in a loop by getting the count of one, and it's the same array index reference with all 4 inputs. Try that and then use this code to check: `if (!empty($_POST)) {
   $items = count($_POST['invoiceNo']);
   echo 'Total Entries: ', $items, ':<br>';
   for ($i = 0; $i < $items; $i++) {
       echo '<br>', $_POST['invoiceNo'][$i];
       echo ', ', $_POST['date'][$i];
       echo ', ', $_POST['desc'][$i];
       echo ', ', $_POST['amt'][$i];
   }
}`

Comment: ...(continued) then inside the loop, you can do whatever query is needed with the retrieved values. The array [looks like this](https://imgbox.com/T21MqIF0) after submit. In that output, all the `[0]` indexes correspond to the 1st row, all the `[1]` indexes to the 2nd row, and so on.

Comment: Yes, I can now get the values after submission. Thank you Paul for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need any of the `keyup`, you can use the `amt` to `delegate` the handling to any of those.

Basically, remove this handling:

```
$('.amt').each(function() {

  $(this).keyup(function() {
    calculateSum();
  });
});

$('.amt' + j).each(function() {

  $(this).keyup(function() {
    calculateSum();
  });
  j++;
});
```

Replace with:

```
// Use a change event delegate on amt
$('#tab_logic').on('change', '.amt', function() {
    calculateSum();
});
```

Try the runnable example below.

Click the spinner buttons, the sum change is immediate. If a value is typed in, the sum updates after the field loses focus.

```html
<?php
    $sno = 1;
?>

  <html>

  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      
      #summation {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #174C68;
      }
      
      .amt {
        background-color: #FEFFB0;
        //font-weight: bold;
        text-align: right;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th />&nbsp;
                <th>Invoice No.</th>
                <th>Invoice Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr id='addr0'>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $sno;?>
                </td>
                <td width="40px"><input class="txt" type="text" name="invoiceNo" style="text-transform:uppercase" /></td>
                <td><input type="date" name="date" /></td>
                <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" /></td>
                <td><input class="amt" type="number" name="amt" min="0" step="0.01" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr id='addr1'></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left">Add Row</button>

      <table>
        <tr id="summation">
          <td align="right" colspan="3">Total Sum :</td>
          <td align="right" colspan="2"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 1;
        var j = 1;
        $("#add_row").click(function() {
          $('#addr' + i).html("<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td><input type='text' name='invoiceNo" + i + "' class='form-control input-md' style='text-transform:uppercase'/></td><td><input type='date' name='date" + i + "' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='text" + i + "' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='number' name='amt" + i + "' class='amt' min='0' step='0.01'/></td>");

          $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
          i++;
        });
      });

      // Use an event delegate on amt
      $('#tab_logic').on('change', '.amt', function() {
          calculateSum();
      });

      function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        $(".amt").each(function() {

          if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
          }

        });
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
      }
    </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Can I check how can I get the values of the subsequent rows when I submit the form? Currently, I'm able to get the values from the 1st row.

Comment: Sorry, new to this forum. How can I add code snippet in comments?